# How can I ssh into "Web App On Linux" docker container on Azure?

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

How can I ssh into the container with the new "Web App On Linux" service?

It is currently in preview mode, I'm not sure that it is not possible yet or I have overseen the settings.

Comment: pretty sure you don't

Comment: For now, it is not possible. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/17473870-ssh-for-azure-app-services-for-linux).

Comment: Hi @Walter-MSFT, Thank you for your reply, would be as kind to state as "answer", so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, It is not possible. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/17473870-ssh-for-azure-app-services-for-linux).

Update on 2017-6-8

Now, it is possible, please refer to [SSH support for Azure Web App on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-ssh-support).

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example that I got working with ssh together with a asp.net core app in linux container:

**Dockerfile**

```
#base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base

#ssh
ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
        && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd 

COPY MyApp/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY MyApp/init.sh /usr/local/bin/

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 443 2222

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    
ENTRYPOINT ["bash","init.sh"]
```

**init.sh** in root folder of .net core project

```
service ssh start
dotnet MyApp.dll
```

**sshd_config** in root folder of .net core project

```
#
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#

Port            2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers                 aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc
MACs                    hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PrintMotd       no
IgnoreRhosts        no
#deprecated option 
#RhostsAuthentication   no
RhostsRSAAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication   no 
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     yes
```

[image]

Comment: I could not get this working with this and @augdog answer. App service fails to run init,sh> error in logs: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"init.sh\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having issues with @[sgedda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024044/sgedda)'s answer as @[Manish Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225596/manish-jain) is having, try using:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "init.sh"]
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (4/1/2019) it is possible according to this doc: [Connect to Web App for Containers using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image#connect-to-web-app-for-containers-using-ssh). It's kind of hacking but it does the trick.

*Not an April fool's joke.*

Comment: What is SSH_PASSWD here? Is it any random pass or is it login creds?

Answer (score 2):

I found @Sgedda's reply to be very helpful. I followed his example to the letter, but I kept getting this error `exec user process caused "exec format error"`

In addition to implementing his example, I also did the following

1. Added `#!/bin/bash` as the 1st line of the *init.sh* file. It's important that there is NOTHING in front of it nor at the end of that line AND that it's the 1st line in the file. `service ssh start` is line 2.
2. Changed the encoding of the *init.sh* and *sshd_config* files to `ISO 8859-15` using VS Code[image]
3. Changed the line endings of the *init.sh* and *sshd_config* files to `LF` using VS Code
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. But depending on what you want to do (e.g. view log files), you could use bash from Kudu (via Advanced Tools > Debug console > Bash)

That said, Web App On Linux is in preview - so SSH may be possible in the future!

Comment: you can literally do nothing with bash with the container itself, so its of 0 use