# How do I run commands remotely on a container launched with App Services for Containers?

Tags: azure

I'm trying out the new webapp service for linux/containers with a custom docker image I've pushed up to an ACR.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/webapp-for-containers-overview/

We've got it up and running, a django app, nicely.

What I need to do now though is to be able to run one off commands in the containers we're making.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish that?

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The current approach for doing that in App Service Linux is to enable SSH to your container - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-ssh-support

```
# ------------------------
# SSH Server support
# ------------------------
RUN apt-get update \ 
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
```

You can then SSH into it through the Kudu console (which uses WebSSH) -

[image: WebSSH]

Comment: Thanks evilSnobu, I'll give that a try.  How do I get access to the Kudu console?

Comment: I just noticed something "Web Apps for Containers are not supported with a work or school login. Sign out before proceeding" Does that mean I can't use the service with a work azure account?

Comment: SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:2222Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:2222 CREDENTIALS

Comment: Make sure your container works locally first and listens on 2222/TCP for those credentials.

Comment: Thanks snobu, I wasn't exposing port 2222 in the container!! Doh!

Comment: I got it working with my asp.net core app, see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704656/how-can-i-ssh-into-web-app-on-linux-docker-container-on-azure/59899525#59899525

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its not possible with Azure Web App yet.

Useful links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-ssh-support
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image#troubleshooting

Comment: Do you know of any way to get at some logs for the container?  This is bloody silly

Comment: updated answer, you can use ssh or get logs from container

Comment: thanks again, I'm not seeing a docker log with kudu, ssh is borked.  It's saying this docker run returned: STDOUT>> 1ff23c33dec88f4e8249a4aa87c91b51de738a0af0baac5a756ecae29e168024 ? Any ideas?